# How do I save my preferences after moving components around in the SSIS Toolbox?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm working with SSIS 2012 (SQL Server Data tools), which runs in the VS 2010 Shell.
This is my first time working on a project that required us to install some 3rd party SSIS components. (SSIS-PowerPack from ZappySys.com)
When the components install, they all appear in the tool box under "Common".
I can move each component to more appropriate sections of the tool box by right clicking and choosing “Move to Other Sources” or “Move to Other Destinations”, however then next time I open the project, they’ve all snapped back to common. How can I save my preferences, or change the defaults so these components stay where I want them?

Edit: Just wante to add that its not strictly related to the 3rd part vendor's components, Microsoft's own OData Source also appears in Common instead of Other Sources after install, and also snaps back to Common on the next project load if you try to move it.

Comment: I've never moved components in the SSIS toolbox before... if no one else here has you can always contact the vendor... they must know a bit about Visual Studio internals.